# DC Motor Controller using only one button?

Tags: dc-motor, motor-controller

I have been trying to create a DC motor controller that can do numerous actions with just the use of one button.

Basically when I click it has to go on way, when I click again it has to stop, and again it has to go the other way and vise versa only using one button. I've been attempting this with a D-FLIP-FLOP, but I have encountered multiple problems along the way that have me thinking new ways to solve it. Any ideas to this silly, but funny problem?

Comment: Seems like a job for a small microcontroller.

Comment: Yes. Solve it using a microprocessor

Comment: You can also differentiate between short press and long press, double click etc. using only that one button.

Comment: I don't want to do it with a microprocessor. Takes all the fun out of it

Comment: 2 bit counter (4 different modes) - logic gates (decoder) - power amplifier (h-bridge)

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzRr2L.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. A [CD4017](http://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/cd4017b) decade counter with reset on Q4.*

How it works:

- On each press of SW1 the outputs switch sequentially on Q0, Q1, etc.
- Q1 is wired to your forward control and Q3 is wired to your reverse control.  When Q0 or Q2 is on the motor is off.
- When Q4 is reached it pulls the reset pin high and resets the count.

Problem: on power-up the counter could be at any state including > 4. A solution to this is shown in my answer to [Power circuit with a push button](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/356963/power-circuit-with-a-push-button/356995#356995). Alternatively you can feed the reset pin via diodes connected to Q4, 5, 6, 7, 8 and 9 to force a reset should the device power up in one of those states.